# How to edit previous "omnibar" search in Chrome. (à la Safari)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

It has been said elsewhere (sorry can't find my references) that <kbd>Control</kbd> `+` <kbd>e</kbd> and/or <kbd>Control</kbd>`+`<kbd>k</kbd>, or even <kbd>F6</kbd> allow you to "jump" to the "Search" box in an existing Google search results page (this is in Chrome).  However, none of these combos work for me (even when using <kbd>Command</kbd> in lieu of <kbd>Control</kbd>.

I am looking to reproduce my search workflow / the behavior as seen in Safari, below (in which I hit <kbd>Command</kbd>`+`<kbd>l</kbd>, jumping to the URL bar, which has my prior search terms)..

[image: safari flow]

However, in Chrome, I just end up editing a messy URL (which doesn't work), so I have to retype my entire search query again.

[image]

Sounds silly, but actually, cumulatively wastes a LOT of time.  Any fixes, my gurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a browser-independent solution, specific to Google, of course: Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>! Alternatively, you can also just start typing (using any of the <kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>Z</kbd> keys), it’ll automatically be redirected to the search box (separated by a space).

These and other useful shortcuts are listed [here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/web/Google-Instant-Search.html).

Comment: I just tried both.  Neither worked. (Version 49.0.2588.0 canary (64-bit))

Comment: These shortcuts only work when Instant Search is enabled.

Comment: Thank you.  ..I was beginning to despair that this _specific, yet perpetual and personal_ pet-peeve might remain unresolved. Insanity, averted.